# Two Limits Equal - Proof that $\lim_{n\to\infty }a_n=L$ implies $\lim_{n\to\infty }\frac{\sum_1^na_k}n=L$

Tags: calculus, limits

Problem: Given that $\lim_{n\to\infty }a_n=L$ and $m_n=\frac{\sum_{1}^{n}a_k}{n}$. Prove that $\lim m_n=L$

Proof: We have $\sum_{1}^{n}a_k=na_k$, so $m_n=\frac{\sum_{1}^{n}a_k}{n}=\frac{na_k}{n}=a_k$ and $\lim a_k=L.\square$

Is this a correct proof? I am confused with the subscripts $m$ and $k$ and not sure if I am using the right one in the right spot, in the proof.
Thanks.

Comment: I think that the index on the summation is supposed to be $k$. That is, "$\sum_1^n a_k$" means $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n$, not $a_k+a_k+\cdots+a_k$ ($n$ summands); so you don't have that the sum is equal to $na_k$. Otherwise, what you write is false, because if $k$ is fixed, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_k = a_k$, not $L$.

Comment: @Bill Cook: Since the confusion arises from the lack of indices in what he wrote, I would think it best for the OP to understand their importance rather than for you to add them "in spite" of him...

Comment: Yes, the lack of indices/subscripts makes the issue confusing. That's why they are important! It's important to know what the indices mean; for example, the summation has a "hidden index" which you did not write. It should "really" be $$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k.$$ Was it written this way in your assignment?

Comment: Just wanted to mention that this can be obtained from Stolz-Cesaro: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=stolz

Comment: Another thing which might be worth mentioning is that the sequence $(m_n)$ is called [Cesàro mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cesaro_mean) of the sequence $(a_n)$.

Comment: Yes, I see it know, that k is going from 1 to n, that makes sense, thank you for the help.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate, since here the OP is asking if a particular proof is valid. In the "duplicate" question, the OP is asking for any proof. (Though the fact that the OP here accepted an alternate proof muddies the issue.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the correct proof: Given any $\epsilon>0$, since $\lim_{n\to \infty }a_n=L$, there exists $N_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$|a_k-L|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}\mbox{ for }k\geq N_0.$$
Now, for the given $\epsilon$ and $N_0$, we can choose an integer $N_1$ large enough such that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{N_0}|a_k|+N_0|L|<\frac{N_1\epsilon}{2}.$$
Hence, for $n\geq N_2:=\max\{N_0,N_1\}$, we have
$$|m_n-L|=\Big|\frac{\sum_{k=1}^na_k}{n}-L\Big|=\Big|\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n(a_k-L)}{n}\Big|
\leq\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{N_0}|a_k-L|}{n}+\frac{\sum_{k=N_0+1}^n|a_k-L|}{n}:=I+II<\epsilon,$$
because
$$I=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{N_0}|a_k-L|}{n}\leq\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{N_0}|a_k|+N_0|L|}{N_2}\leq\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{N_0}|a_k|+N_0|L|}{N_1}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
and
$$II=\frac{\sum_{k=N_0+1}^n|a_k-L|}{n}<\frac{\sum_{k=N_0+1}^n\epsilon/2}{n}=\frac{(n-N_0)\epsilon/2}{n}\leq\frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$ 
Therefore, by definition, we have
$$\lim_{n\to \infty } m_n=L$$