# Find the limit (if it exist) $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\pi+\sqrt{\pi}+\cdots+\sqrt[n]{\pi}}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Find the limit (if it exist) $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\pi+\sqrt{\pi}+\cdots+\sqrt[n]{\pi}}{n}$

I have no idea about this.

Comment: Hint: What is the limit of the sequence $(\pi)^{1/n}$?

Comment: Hint: $\pi$ is a red herring.

Comment: For $k\gt 1000$, $\sqrt[k]{\pi}$ is close to $1$. For $n\gt 1,000,000$, the part from $k=1$ to $k=1000$ makes no big difference.

Comment: You could replace Pi by any number, the limit will always be 1 (1+ if the number is greater than 1, 1- if the number is lower than 1)

Comment: I can find the upper limit \pi and the lower limit 1, but I have no idea the next step.

Comment: The limit should be one.

Comment: I see. But how can I get the upper limit if I want to use squeeze theorem? I tried a lot of methods but failed.

Comment: You should prove the more general statement: if $a_n$ is any sequence that converges to the finite number $L$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}n = L$.

Answer (score 1):

Following Greg's idea, note that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\pi^{1/n}=1$ and use the result of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83850/two-limits-equal-proof).